# How does one map a graph into a feature space?

Tags: algorithms, graph-theory

Assuming there is an undirected weighted graph. How can one convey it's geometrical structure into a feature space? Are there any common practices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no canonical way of representing a graph in a feature space. One possible way to go is to use a graph embedding algorithm. Examples are isomap, t-SNE and mapping based on eigenvectors of graph laplacian. But such mappings may not produce nice features for machine learning.

You can also have a look at graph kernels literature. They provide a direct method to find a similarity measure between graphs, and some can deal with node labels.

Finding a canonical representation for a graph can solve the graph isomorphism problem, which is supposed to be a hard problem (not known to be P or NP).

Comment: Thanks. But so far multidimensional scaling is the answer. To my knowledge in general graph embedding algorithms might not find a solution.

Comment: for multidimensional scaling, you need a proper distance function. Isomap is applying multidimensional scaling on shortest path distances extracted from graph.

Comment: I got more or less defined similarity measure, so I guess I'll try the classic MDS but will also experiment with Isomap. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is still a problem but a huge amount of graph embedding methods, particularly deep learning addresses this problem. It is also called Graph representation learning. for example, Standford lecture https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YrhBZUtgG4E&t=2431s